# How do I use a conditional to display Relationships content?

Tags: relationships, conditionals, related-entries

I am working with three Relationship fields and I would like to be able to display a section only if there are any related articles in that section.

I tried this without success:

```
{if related_tips != ""}
  <h3>Related Tips</h3>
   <ul>
    {related_tips}
      <li><a href="{site_url}in_the_garden/decorating_tip/{related_tips:url_title}">{related_tips:title}</a> </li>
    {/related_tips}
   </ul>                
{/if}
```

I would appreciate some guidance on how this should be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the != '' part of your equasion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the count and total results variables, but namespaced with the name of your relationship field:

```
{relationship_field}

    {if relationship_field:count ==1}
        <ol>
    {/if}

    <li>{relationship_field:title}</li>

    {if relationship_field:count == relationship_field:total_results}
        </ol>
    {/if}

{/relationship_field}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, That appears to solve the problem. I am not sure I totally understand the logic behind the conditionals around the <ol>. If you could share a tad more on that, I would appreciate it.

Also, I would like to thank you for your amazing tutorials. It was your Small Business site tutorial that I went through in 2008 that turned the EE lightbulb on in my mind. Since then I have built more than 50 EE sites and will always be grateful for your teaching.

Comment: Basically this logic is saying "only spit out the ordered list markup if there are going to be items in the list". It's just a way to ensure that you would never get empty <ol></ol> markup in your rendered code.

And thanks for the comments - always good to hear as I look at another necessary edit of the book..;)